# Array element being added after key change

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to sort out my array, just remove some duplicate elements etc... It all works great and looks like this when i output it

```
array(3) { ["addon_mat_3"]=> string(2) "15" ["addon_mat_7"]=> string(1) "7" ["addon_mat_15"]=> string(1) "9" }
```

The above is with this code

```
foreach ($new_shopping_list_array as $columnName => $columnData) {
    if(is_numeric($columnName)){
        unset($new_shopping_list_array[$columnName]);    
    }     
    if($columnName == 'addon_id'){
        unset($new_shopping_list_array[$columnName]);    
    }     
    if($columnData == 0){
        unset($new_shopping_list_array[$columnName]);    
    }



}
```

However, if i add the else as show below, which i need as it removes the first 10 characters from the array key, then i all of a sudden get a fourth element added to the array with key "0".

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "9" [3]=> string(2) "15" [7]=> string(1) "7" [15]=> string(1) "9" }
```

This code

```
foreach ($new_shopping_list_array as $columnName => $columnData) {
    if(is_numeric($columnName)){
        unset($new_shopping_list_array[$columnName]);    
    }     
    if($columnName == 'addon_id'){
        unset($new_shopping_list_array[$columnName]);    
    }     
    if($columnData == 0){
        unset($new_shopping_list_array[$columnName]);    
    }else{

        $new_columnName = substr($columnName, 10);
        unset($new_shopping_list_array[$columnName]);
        $new_shopping_list_array[$new_columnName] = $columnData;
    }



}
```

Everything else is great, apart from that fourth element added, what am i doing wrong,

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: Are you sure that is your full code? I just ran it on phpfiddle.org - [http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ph0-4vw](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ph0-4vw) and it echo'ed out just array(3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should work, but you could do the whole thing in a few less lines:

```
$flipped = array_flip($new_shopping_list_array);
foreach ($flipped as $value => &$key) {
    if($key == "addon_id" || is_numeric($key) || $value == 0) { 
        unset($flipped[$value]);
    } else {
        $key = substr($key,10);
    }
}
$new_shopping_list_array = array_flip($flipped);
```